# Using Bayes Law to Show that Two Expressions Are Equal

Tags: probability

I have the following two expressions:

Expression 1: $$\dfrac{~\dfrac{P(D\mid E)}{P(D\mid\overline{E})}~}{\dfrac{P(\overline{D}\mid E)}{P(\overline{D}\mid\overline{E})}}$$

Expression 2:

$$\dfrac{~\dfrac{P(E\mid D)}{P(E\mid \overline{D})}~}{\dfrac{P(\overline{E}\mid D)}{P(\overline{E}\mid\overline{D})}}$$

**My Question:** I am trying to determine if Expression 1 is equal to Expression 2

I think I might be able to use Bayes Law and the Laws of Probabilities to show this. Here is what I tried so far - I derived a series of alternate relationships:

$$\begin{align*}
P(E\mid D) &= \dfrac{P(D\mid E) \cdot P(E)}{P(D)} \\
P(E\mid\overline{D}) &= \dfrac{P(\overline{D}\mid E) \cdot P(E)}{P(\overline{D})} \\
P(\overline{E}\mid D) &= \dfrac{P(D\mid\overline{E}) \cdot P(\overline{E})}{P(D)} \\
P(\overline{E}\mid\overline{D}) &= \dfrac{P(\overline{D}\mid\overline{E}) \cdot P(\overline{E})}{P(\overline{D})}
\end{align*}$$

Now, if I take Expression 2 and substitute these alternate relationships, I think I can show that Expression 1 and Expression 2 are equal.

Have I done this correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  That works.

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{~\dfrac{P(D\mid E)}{P(D\mid\overline{E})}~}{\dfrac{P(\overline{D}\mid E)}{P(\overline{D}\mid\overline{E})}}
 &=\dfrac{~P(D\mid E)~P(\overline{D}\mid\overline{E})~}{P(D\mid\overline{E})~P(\overline{D}\mid E)}
\\[1ex]
 &= \dfrac{~P(E\mid D)~P(\overline{E}\mid\overline{D})~\cdot~P(D)P(\overline D)~/~P(E)P(\overline E)}{P(E\mid\overline{D})~P(\overline{E}\mid D)~\cdot~P(\overline D)P(D)~/~P(\overline E)P(E)}
\\[2ex]
 &= \dfrac{~\dfrac{P(E\mid D)}{P(E\mid\overline{D})}~}{\dfrac{P(\overline{E}\mid D)}{P(\overline{E}\mid\overline{D})}}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are on the right track. If you simplify Expression 2 using the substitutions, you get: $$\frac{\frac{P(E|D)}{P(E|\overline{D})}}{\frac{P(\overline{E}|D)}{P(\overline{E}|\overline{D})}} = \frac{\frac{P(D|E)\cdot P(E) \cdot P(D)}{P(D) \cdot P(\overline{D}|E) \cdot P(E)}}{\frac{P(D|\overline{E})\cdot P(\overline{E}) \cdot P(\overline{D})}{P(\overline{D}) \cdot P(\overline{D}|\overline{E}) \cdot P(\overline{E})}} = \frac{\frac{P(D|E)}{P(\overline{D}|E)}}{\frac{P(D|\overline{E})}{P(\overline{D}|\overline{E})}} = \frac{\frac{P(D|E)}{P(D|\overline{E})}}{\frac{P(\overline{D}|E) }{P(\overline{D}|\overline{E})}}$$

RHS above is same as the Expression 1, therefore we get that Expression 1 is equal to Expression 2.